# Pyscf installation failed "Failed building wheel for pyscf" in new conda environment

Tags: python, installation, pip

I use Anaconda on Windows 10 and tried installing pyscf. First, I created a new conda environment with python 3.12. Then I ran
`pip install --prefer-binary pyscf`
but ended up with
`ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscf`

I assumed that I wouldn't even have to build the wheel, when installing it in this manner, but that seems to be incorrect.
I then ran
`pip install cmake`
which worked, but did not solve the issue. The new error message contains
`CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

Do I have to go further with installing a c compiler, or is there a way to directly install pyscf?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/4150f854ff293c89ce3bb1907c9d0710a960e66d/setup.py#L36-L38 OS: all kinds of Unix but Windows is not listed at all. Try WSL, QEMU or Docker with Linux.

Comment: https://anaconda.org/search?q=pyscf The same: linux-64, linux-aarch64, linux-ppc64le, osx-64. No Windows.

Comment: https://pyscf.org/install.html states "The pip package provides a precompiled PySCF code (python wheel) which works on almost all Linux systems, and most of Mac OS X systems, and the Ubuntu subsystems on Windows 10."

I must have misread this as "...and on Windows 10". Thank you!

Comment: "*…Ubuntu subsystems on Windows…*" That is, WSL2.